# Iterating through JSON format

Tags: json, iterator, format, qlikview, qliksense

i have the following problem: i am sending a JSON File from a webservice into a extension to Qlik Sense and i am getting the following response:

"{"rownumber":1,"ID":1}{"rownumber":2,"ID":2}"

The type of the response is string. My question is how can i change the format to iterate through each element of this.

I have already tried the `JSON.parse(result)` and `JSON.stringify(result)` functions but the result was nothing that i can work with. Last one changed the
result to:

"{"rownumber":1,"ID":1}{"rownumber":2,"ID":2}"

Comment: Are they really run together like that, or are they on separate lines? The latter is called [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) for which you could probably find a parser etc. (Or if not, it's trivial to parse.)

Comment: **Please folks**, could we **not** have answers posting naive code that breaks the string up on `}`, completely ignoring the complexity of the real world? Thanks in advance. ;-)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or an answer!), please *stick around* so you can reply to anything that comes up in the comments.